# C# - List Webpage Source Files (like from inspect element)

Tags: c#, list, file

So basically what I'm trying to do is list all the source files a webpage uses. The source files you find when you inspect element. For example, if you inspect element a discord page and go to the "sources" tab you see these files: http://prntscr.com/oedg0r. I'm not sure if there's some way to do it through WebClient. I just know the download "DownloadString" function doesn't help me.

Comment: Search on "web scraping", "web crawler", "web spider" for many topics here and on the web.  Note that you can't get the actual source for script pages (PHP, ASPX, JSP, etc.) since the code runs on the server and you can only see the results that were sent to the client.

Comment: @DaveS i don't need the source, i just want to see the files used. If you look at that screenshot, i don't care for the source in those files I just want to be able to list their names.

Comment: Makes sense if you only want to know what files the browser client uses.  There's no way to find (from a client) what additional files a script page might have included for its own use (such as code libraries) but not linked to in its results.

Comment: @DaveS I am pretty sure they use the files I'm looking for. In the end though, I'm just looking for a way to list the files or folders (as seen in the picture). So if I can only get the ones that are being used, that would still be helpful. Do you know how this could be done or where I could look/search for answers?

Comment: The search I recommended should find you library code for C#.  If you just want to know and don't mind doing it manually, the F12 key developer tools in Google Chrome will show you using the Network tab.